# How to read this longest increasing subsequence recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

i'm practicing my recurrence relations. As a example problem, I am looking at the longest increasing subsequence (LIS) problem.
Given a list [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3] find a longest increasing subsequence (could be [3,4,5,9] or [1,4,5,6])
In this problem, I am only concerned with finding the length of such a subsequence, not the actual sequence.

The algorithm I can roughly describe as follows:

```
 1: start at first element i, check if it contains a longest increasing subsequence.
 If it does, store a number corresponding to the length of that subsequence at that element in the sequence
 2. Move one item ahead to item i, check if we can "extend" any of the already defined subsequences with element i (is element i larger than preceeding elements) by this item i. element i will extend the largest subsequence that it is able to.
 3. keep moving i along until the end of the list.
```

For further clarification on the algorithms one can follow these sources:

```
 -https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1138/handouts/140%20Guide%20to%20Dynamic%20Programming.pdf
 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fV-TF4OvZpk
```

However, what I am struggling with is the recurrence relation for this problem, which I have found in this form:
[image]

The base case makes perfect sense, if i is 0, then there can be no increasing subsequence.

Also the first argument "1" to the max() function makes perfect sense, if there is no preceeding item that is smaller than item i.

What confuses me is the second argument to max(), which itself is a max() function, but only with one argument? I thought max() was a function that had to take multiplie parameters?

I have tried rewriting this with a bit of prose, would this amount to the same thing?:
[image]

Comment: *length( find largest preceding subsequence that ends in j for all j < i )  + 1* is probably better...but I think you got it.

Comment: *"What confuses me is the second argument to max(), which itself is a max() function, but only with one argument?"* The argument to the second max() function is actually the set of values where `j < i` and `A[j] < A[i]`. In other words, there's an implied loop that generates multiple choices.

Comment: thanks a lot, this makes it much clearer :)